Custom Authentication flow with Hosted UI in Amazon Cognito
I know that in Amazon Cognito, to achieve OIDC flow, I have to go with the hosted UI option. But for the local authentication, I want to replace the username/password login method with something else (e.g., email OTP or SMS OTP). I know that to use custom authentication flow (using Lambda), I have to go with Amazon Cognito user pool API. I have gone through this article, and know the pros and cons of both Hosted UI and Custom UI. Unfortunately, I want to achieve a mix of hosted UI with custom authentication flow since my application seems to understand only OIDC protocol.
Could someone help me shed a light on?
